# Find rows containing all keywords within a string across multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to create a universal search functionality. The goal is to compare the values of multiple columns and see if **all** of the provided keywords appear in those columns. For various reasons, using a Full Text Index and `CONTAINS` is not an option, nor is utilizing a CLR function. Are there any other options to solve this problem?

Example:

```
----------------------------------------------------
|    Row    |    Col1    |    Col2    |    Col3    |
----------------------------------------------------
|     1     |    Foo     |    Bar     |    Stack   |
----------------------------------------------------
|     2     |    Foo     |    Blitz   |    Stack   |
----------------------------------------------------
|     3     |    Foo     |     Foo    |     Bar    |
----------------------------------------------------
```

Search text "Foo Bar" matches Rows 1 and 3.

Search text "Foo Stack" matches Rows 1, and 2.

Search Text "Foo" matches Rows 1, 2 and 3.

Search text "Foo Bar Stack Blitz" matches no rows.

Search text "Foo Blitz" matches Row 2.

Comment: Is this case sensitive? Does "Foo" match "Food" or are you only looking for exact word matches? Is the space character your word delimiter?

Comment: Foo would match Food, and the space character in the search string is the word delimiter

Comment: Are you limited to passing the search as a space delimited string or could you pass a data set such as a Table Valued Parameter ? SQL is not great at string splitting, and although there are pretty good splitters like DelimitedSplit8K, it makes sense to not have to split a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a string splitter and do this. I use [Jeff Moden's splitter](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) but you can use your favorite. This essentially splits the string on the space, and then does a `FULL JOIN` and only returns rows where there is a mach for each word. This is handy since it doesn't care the order of the words in the string. i.e. `Foo Bar` is the same as `Bar Foo`.

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c0caa/2/0)**

```
declare @table table ([Row] int identity (1,1), Col1 char(3), Col2 varchar(6), Col3 varchar(6))
insert into @table
values

('Foo','Bar','Stack'),
('Foo','Blitz','Stack'),
('Foo','Foo','Bar')


declare @search varchar(64)

set @search = 'Foo Bar'

select distinct
    t.*
from @table t
full join 
    dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@search,' ') s on
    s.Item = t.Col1
    or s.Item = t.Col2
    or s.Item = t.Col3
where
    t.Row is not null
group by
    t.Row
    ,t.Col1
    ,t.Col2
    ,t.Col3
having
    count(*) = (select max(ItemNumber) from dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@search,' '))
```

Comment: This assumes that each value in the three columns in question is a single word. That seems supported by the sample data, but can't be proven (until or unless the OP accepts the answer, or comments on it).

Comment: Correct @RDFozz and i based if off the sample data and no delimiter in their "search string"

Answer (score 0):

**Try using charindex:**

For example, I'm looking for the letter 'o' in two columns in msdb.dbo.sysjobs table. Because of the conditional 'and' only rows that meet both search conditions are returned.

```
 declare @searchvar varchar(255)='o'
 select * from msdb.dbo.sysjobs where  charindex(@searchvar,description) > 0 and charindex (@searchvar, name)> 0
```

**Try a temporary table to hold your search stack and a loop to process through the search:**

OK, got your message, see what you think of this iteration:

```
  set nocount on
  declare @match int=1,@found int=0,@rowcount int =1, @rowmax int =0, @searchvar varchar(255)
    create table #SearchStack
  (
  PK int identity(1,1),
  searchvar varchar(255)
  )

  insert into #searchStack (searchvar) values('n')
  insert into #searchStack (searchvar) values('o')

  select @rowmax =count(*) from #searchstack

  while (@rowcount <=@rowmax)
  begin
      select @searchvar = searchvar from #searchstack where PK = @rowcount
      if  (select count(*) from msdb.dbo.sysjobs where  charindex(@searchvar,description) > 0 and charindex (@searchvar, name)> 0 ) > 0 set @found =1
      select @match = @match * @found
      select @rowcount = @rowcount + 1
  end
  if  (@match> 0) print 'all rows in searchstack match'
  drop table #searchstack
```

**Or, build some dynamic SQL to avoid the while/loop for processing:**

If you're not a fan of a while/loop for processing, you can use it for some dynamic SQL instead--but here you're processing every row. At least the while-loop (above) you can program an early exit on @found=0 if you want:

```
 set nocount on
declare @match int=1,@found int=0,@rowcount int =1, @rowmax int =0, @searchvar varchar(255), @searchSQL  varchar(max)= 'select * from msdb.dbo.sysjobs where '
    create table #SearchStack
  (
  PK int identity(1,1),
  searchvar varchar(255)
  )

  insert into #searchStack (searchvar) values('n')
  insert into #searchStack (searchvar) values('o')

  select @rowmax =count(*) from #searchstack

  while (@rowcount <=@rowmax)
  begin

      select @searchvar = searchvar from #searchstack where PK = @rowcount
      select @searchSQL= @searchSQL + ' (charindex('''+@searchvar+''',description) > 0 and charindex ('''+@searchvar+''', name)> 0) AND '
      select @rowcount = @rowcount + 1
  end
  IF charindex(' DNA ', reverse(@searchSQL))=1 set @searchSQL = substring(@searchSQL,0,len(@searchSQL) -3)
  print @searchSQL
  drop table #searchstack

  exec(@searchSQL)
```

Comment: Note from my example: I need to find if all of an arbitrary number of search strings appear, not just one word, and they can appear in any order.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid a while loop for performance reasons (this comparison could be across tens or hundreds of thousands of rows), but it could work in a pinch. Let me sit on the question for a bit and if no one has a more set-based solution I'll accept the answer.

Comment: Sure thing, to speed things up, you could cancel out of the loop when you encounter the first @found=0 as well.  while (@rowcount <=@rowmax or @found=0)--just initialize @found to =1 initially so it won't exit early and 'else' @ found =0 in the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try concatenating the columns together and use the LIKE operator.

```
select Row
from table1
where col1 + ' ' + col2 +' '+col3 LIKE '%<string>%'
```

This will perform extremely badly once your database is very large, but it will work.
There are cases where this will not work. As @scsimon mentioned - if the order of the keywords does not matter, then this will fail miserably.

Comment: This would work if the order of the words mattered (up to the OP if they do, but i don't think that's the case). i.e. `Bar Foo` wouldn't return anything with this method. Straight forward though.

Comment: This would also perform terribly over a large number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach to this would be to dynamically generate your query so that it ends up along the lines of:

```
SELECT  match1.[Row]
FROM (
    SELECT  [Row]
    FROM    TableName
    WHERE   'foo' in (Col1, Col2, Col3)) match1
JOIN (
    SELECT  [Row]
    FROM    TableName
    WHERE   'bar' IN (Col1, Col2, Col3)) match2
    ON match1.[Row] = match2.[Row]
JOIN (
    SELECT  [Row]
    FROM    TableName
    WHERE   'stack' IN (Col1, Col2, Col3)) match3
    ON match2.[Row] = match3.[Row]
```

You'd need to add a join for each additional search parameter. I'm not sure what optimizations are available with this approach though.